# Different results with different methods to same limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm considering this limit:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cos(x) - \sin(x)}{x \sin^2(x)}$$

If I apply de l'Hôpital's rule I get $-\frac{1}{3}$, while if I immediately simplify the $x$ like this:

$$\frac{\cos(x) - \frac{\sin(x)}{x}}{\sin^2(x)}$$

I get $-\frac{1}{2}$ as result, because I write it as (remembering that $\frac{sin(x)}{x} = 1$):

$$\frac{cos(x) - 1}{x^2}$$

which I simplify it with $-\frac{1}{2}$.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: How are you getting $-1/2$? We need to see all of your work to find the error.

Comment: The second rearrangement is an indeterminate form yet

Comment: @TheCount I updated my answer

Comment: You can't replace only a part of an expression with its limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Your error is in the second step. You substitute $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ by its limit, $1$. But this is getting rid of the low-order terms, *which matter*.

---

One way to see it rigorously is to do a polynomial approximation near $0$, that is a **Taylor expansion**: when $x\to 0$,
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1-\frac{x^2}{6} + o(x^2)
$$
so that you neglect a term "behaving like" $\frac{x^2}{6}$. Does it matter? Well, again, near $0$: we have
$$
\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2} +o(x^2) \tag{1}
$$
so
$$\begin{align}
\cos x - 1 &= -\frac{x^2}{2} +o(x^2) \tag{2}\\
\cos x - \frac{\sin x}{x} &= 1-\frac{x^2}{2} +o(x^2) - \left(1-\frac{x^2}{6} + o(x^2)\right)
= -\frac{x^2}{3} +o(x^2) \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
which explains the difference you get between you two methods. *The low-order term you (erroneously) dismissed in the second did have a role to play.*

Comment: Thanks indeed. Can you also point me out how to "prettify" the formulas (I suppose it is done with latex)?

Comment: Yes, this website uses MathJax, which is a (watered-down) version of $\LaTeX$ for the Internet. You basically can use all $\LaTeX$ macros (or most) here, see [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for help.

Comment: @f126ck You can also check the source of all answers to see what the code looks like, for instance by clicking on the "edit" link below.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Before applying l'Hopital rule, use the equivalence $$\sin(x)\sim x \;(x\to 0).$$
it is much easier.

Comment: It means you made a mistake  in the second.

Comment: @SalahFatima Can you point me out the mistake?